# ¿Con qué propiedad css puedo hacer estirar este elemento?

Tags: html, css

tengo en mi página un problema.. quiero bajar hasta el footer el contenedor de los articulos de mi página pero no funciona.. le intento poner a la etiqueta css

```
height= 100%;
```

pero este baja unicamente hasta la paginación.. no puedo usar valores staticos. ¿Qué le aplico?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<section class="fondoArticulos">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="tamano">
            <div class="col-sm-3 barraNavegacion">
                <div class="alinearBuscador">
                    <a href="/"><img src="../images/forte.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo" width="250" height="100" /></a>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div id="navegacionLateral" class="left-sidebar">
                    <h2>menú</h2>
                    <div class="panel-group category-products" id="accordian"><!--category-productsr-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a href="/">
                                        INICIO
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @yield('categorias')
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a href="/#contact">
                                        CONTACTAR
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/category-products-->

                    <div class="price-range">

                        <div class="text-center">
                            <h2>CATÁLOGO</h2>
                            <a target="_blank" href="http://online.fliphtml5.com/jgdk/bjxv/">
                                <img src="https://www.dyna.com.co/uploads/banners/PORTADA%20FORTE.jpg" width="180" height="250" alt="team 1">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shipping text-center">
                        <img src="https://www.dyna.com.co/uploads/banners/forte.jpg" alt="" width="262" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tamano">
            <div id="detalle" class="col-sm-9 padding-center descripcionArticulos">
                <br>

                @yield('contenido')

            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
</section>
```

codigo CSS

```
.tamano {
height: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Podrías colocar el código que estás usando ? Si pasas el estilo así height= 100%; no te daría debe ser con height: 100%;

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Listo bro!

Comment: Bueno imagino que cuando utilizas la directiva @yield y llamas la sección contenido estás haciendo alguna consulta a la DB, no puedes simplemente cargar mas elementos para mermar la paginación y que así baje el contenido ?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez bro, si te fijas en la imagen hay una seccion en color blanco y al lado izquierdo uno negro.. lo que quiero es que la de blanco y negro bajen hasta el final..

Comment: la directiva @yield estoy trayendo un contenido que son los articulos que obtengo de una bd. No puedo mostrar más contenido para mermar la páginación..

Comment: Tienes el sitio en algún lugar al cual pueda acceder? o solo lo tienes local ?

Comment: está local bro.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69133/discussion-between-camilo-vasquez-and-rubxnmc).

Comment: @RubxnMC lee cómo crear un [mcve] y luego actualiza tu pregunta para agregar uno. Sin saber la estructura de tu HTML o cómo se aplican los estilos CSS que tengas, es muy difícil (si no imposible) ayudarte.

Answer (score 2):

Al contenedor padre de los divs .tamano agregale

```
align-items: stretch;
display: flex;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues, puedes usar la propiedad vh, osea

```
.contenedor {
     height: 100vh; 
}
```